How to treat/fill missing data in ohlcv ccxt
I'm trying to find out a solution to treat / fill missing ohlcv data coming from cryptocurrency exchange API.
I'm running this code:
bars = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(symbol, interval, limit = limitklines)
for line in bars:  # Keep only first 5 columns, "date" "open" "high" "low" "close"
    del line[5:]
df = pd.DataFrame(bars, columns=['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])  # 2 dimensional tabular data
return df

and I have situations where in results I have less klines retrieved than defined in limit.
I would like to treat / fill them, so in case that I have no kline for minute or hour (depending on interval used) I fill the missing kline with previous minute / hour data.
I have tried to modify the code, but I have trouble with manipulating pandas DataFrame.
